# How to change the Color of dynamically created divs on click event, who are having same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to change the Color of dynamically created divs on click event, who are having same class?

$(this).css('color', 'pink'); With this we can change the clicked div color.

But I want to change color of clicked to pink and remaing divs color to black.

Any hint please?

Reference code:

```
$('#main_div').on('click','class1', function(){
  $(this).css('color','pink');       
});
```

I am having three divs who are having class "class1". When I click on one div then that div should change to pink and other should be black.

Comment: Did you try .on()? [See here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out,

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eFGJ4/3/)**

**Code:**

```
  $("#main_div").on("click", ".class1", function () {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
        $(".class1").not(this).css("color", "black");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9hZk4/)

CSS

```
    .clrs{
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
            background-color: green;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
        $(function(){
            $('.clrs').click(function(){
                $('.clrs').css('background-color','black');
                $(this).css('background-color','pink');
            })
        })
```

HTML

```
    <div class="clrs"></div>
    <div class="clrs"></div>
    <div class="clrs"></div>
    <div class="clrs"></div>
    <div class="clrs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .on() like this :

```
$('body').on('click','div.yourclassname',function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'pink');
})
```

Comment: I think he needs to change 'background-color' css property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#div").on("click",".red",function(){
    $(this).css("color","pink");
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFGJ4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('#main_div').on('click','class1', function(){
  $('.class1').css('color','black').eq($(this).index()).css('color', 'pink');       
});
```